# gethostbyname not working for external server

Tags: sockets, gethostbyname

I am writing an application with C++ to connect to my server.

I am using `gethostbyname()`. It is working fine when I give host name as 'localhost'. but if i try any other site like google.com, it fails.

Can anyone please tell me what could be going wrong.

I can access those websites through browser. Note: I have proxy set up in my browser.

Is thr proxy causing issue with `gethostbyname()`? if yes, how can I mention proxy in my C++ code?

Comment: Please include some code, what part isnt working in that code and why you think it isnt working/ what you expect it to do.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe in your question, it appears that your machine is on a corporate network that is firewalled off the Internet, all access to the web is via a web proxy, and that your network does not have Internet DNS resolution.

Even if you managed to succeed in resolving an IP address, you will not be able to make an outbound connection, unless your firewall offers a Socks proxy, or an equivalent.

If your intent is to write a client that accesses web sites via HTTP, you will need to use your corporate HTTP proxy to do that. Contact your system administrator for more information.

Comment: You can use a web proxy to reach a non-HTTP server, if it supports the HTTP `CONNECT` method (this is typically used for making HTTPS connections, for instance). Otherwise yes, you would have to use SOCKS or other type of proxy instead.